# Can the following conditions be reflected in EER diagram?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

We have a `User entity` and an `Membership` entity.

Requirement:

1. User's membership expires after 1 year.
2. Membership comes in 5 flavors, (a) basic (b) free .. (e) premium.

I intend to create 2 entities (User, Membership) and relationship between them.

But,
Is it possible / or some way to represent these business rules on an ER diagram ?

Comment: And what did your research find is the way to represent business rules on an ER diagram?

Comment: Can have User more Memberships? Can one membership have more flavors?

User --> Membership (N:M)
Membership -> Flavors (M:L)

Answer (score 0):

EER diagrams have one way to depict the 5 flavors of membership.  It's called specialization.  You can depict the 5 flavors as 5 specialized subtypes or subclasses of membership.

This is only useful if the different flavors have different attributes.

ER diagramming, unlike EER diagramming, does not have this feature.

Once you have depicted your case this way, you are still faced with the question of how to design tables to represent the 5 flavors.